# My app is crashing when it reaches the main activity on versions of android <5

Tags: java, android, android-studio, crash, android-4.1-jelly-bean

The activity xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#3498db"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/topbar"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="15 Years. 4 Days. 30 Events"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="1 Legacy"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="25dp"
                >
                <Button
                    android:background="@drawable/icon2"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:onClick="startEvent"

                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="                 "/>
                <Button
                    android:background="@drawable/icon1"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:onClick="startSch"

                    />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"

                >
                <Button
                    android:background="@drawable/icon3"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"

                    android:onClick="startAbout"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="                 "/>
                <Button
                    android:background="@drawable/icon4"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:onClick="startsponsor"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                >
                <Button
                    android:background="@drawable/icon5"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:onClick="startLeg"


                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="                 "/>
                <Button
                    android:background="@drawable/icon6"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:onClick="startCred"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The java file

```
package com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void startAbout(View view)
{
    Intent abt = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutUs.class);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(abt);

}
public void startsponsor (View view)
{
    Intent ib = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Sponsors.class);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(ib);
}
public void startEvent(View view)
{
    Intent ia = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Events.class);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(ia);

}
public void startSch(View view)
{
    Intent abt = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Schedule.class);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(abt);

}
public void startLeg(View view)
{
    Intent abt = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Legacy.class);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(abt);

}
public void startCred(View view)
{
    Intent abt = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Credits.class);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(abt);

}
}
```

The manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15"
>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/MainPageTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Events"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_events"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AboutUs"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_about_us"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.MainActivity"     />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Legacy"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_legacy"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.MainActivity"     />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Sponsors"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sponsors"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.MainActivity"     />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Credits"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_credits"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Schedule"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_schedule"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".schday1"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_schday1"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Schedule" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SchDay0"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sch_day0"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Schedule" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SchDay2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sch_day2"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Schedule" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SchDay3"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sch_day3"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Schedule" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Technical"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_technical"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Events" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Cultural"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_cultural"
        android:parentActivityName=".Events"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Events" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Literary"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_literary"
        android:parentActivityName=".Events"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Events" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Misc"
        android:label="Miscellaneous Events"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Events" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CFTalkies"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_cftalkies"
        android:parentActivityName=".Cultural"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Misc" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".aa"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_aa"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Misc" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".capture"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_capture"
        android:parentActivityName=".Cultural"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Technical" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".crack"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_crack"
        android:parentActivityName=".Technical"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Technical" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".deeds"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_deeds"
        android:parentActivityName=".Cultural"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Cultural" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".graffity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_graffity"
        android:parentActivityName=".Cultural"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Cultural" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".inverto"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_inverto"
        android:parentActivityName=".Literary"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Literary" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".itquest"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_itquest"
        android:parentActivityName=".Technical"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Technical" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".JonH"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_jon_h"
        android:parentActivityName=".Literary"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Literary" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".JTheP"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_jthe_p"
        android:parentActivityName=".Misc"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Misc" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LInRend"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_lin_rend"
        android:parentActivityName=".Literary"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Literary" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MindsOfK"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_minds_of_k"
        android:parentActivityName=".Cultural"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Cultural" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PBox"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_pbox"
        android:parentActivityName=".Technical"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Technical" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PBrains"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_pbrains"
        android:parentActivityName=".Misc"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Misc" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".morphed"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_morphed"
        android:parentActivityName=".Misc"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Misc" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Picsel"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_picsel"
        android:parentActivityName=".Technical"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Technical" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Robowars"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_robowars"
        android:parentActivityName=".Technical"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Technical" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".siltreat"
        android:label="Silent Treatment"
        android:parentActivityName=".Technical"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Technical" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".sytucs"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sytucs"
        android:parentActivityName=".Misc"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Misc" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TTalk"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ttalk"
        android:parentActivityName=".Technical"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Literary" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".tsplash"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tsplash"
        android:parentActivityName=".Cultural"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Cultural" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".tseasonb"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tseasonb"
        android:parentActivityName=".Technical"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Technical" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".t3f"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_t3f"
        android:parentActivityName=".Technical"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Technical" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TaTale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ta_tale"
        android:parentActivityName=".Literary"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Literary" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".vided"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_vided"
        android:parentActivityName=".Technical"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Technical" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".VDub"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_vdub"
        android:parentActivityName=".Technical"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Technical" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".WebTech"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_web_tech"
        android:parentActivityName=".Technical" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Technical" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".WizPro"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_wiz_pro"
        android:parentActivityName=".Technical" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jaipuriacomputerclub.comfest15.Technical" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

The app crashes on android versions <5 while it runs smoothly on others. There were some errors in the `styles.xml` which I fixed. Now, I don't know what to do!

My Styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark" tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/navblue</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/bgblue</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/navblue</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle" tools:ignore="NewApi">@style/MyActionback</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionback</item>

    </style>

    <style name="MyActionback" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background" tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/navblue</item>
        <item name="background">@color/navblue</item>
        <item name="android:elevation" tools:ignore="NewApi">0dp</item>
        <item name="elevation" >0dp</item>
    </style>
<style name="AppThemeHome" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionback</item>

</style>

<style name="MyActionba" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background" tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/bgblue</item>
    <item name="background">@color/bgblue</item>
    <item name="android:elevation" tools:ignore="NewApi">0dp</item>
    <item name="elevation" >0dp</item>
</style>

<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark" tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/bgblue</item>
</style>
<style name="MainPageTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"/>
```

v11

```
<resources>

<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

Comment: It looks like `AppCompatActivity` is using stuff unavailable in <5. Can you be specific with the errors please?

Comment: My splash page activity triggers on starting the app and starts this activity by itself. I changed the theme used as well with an empty theme with parent as Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar

Comment: I thought AppCompat was supposed to help with backward compatibility :/

Comment: Check your resources that you haven't got anything happening in API specific folders, like in `layout-v21` for example

Comment: Editecd to add styles.xml

Comment: Please add the logacat report/stack trace

Comment: Thanks for the replies, guys. The problem was in a resource file. It was using ripple.